# 来不及爱你 Too late to love you

Tags: meaning, expressions, phrase, equivalent-phrase

why the phrase **来不及** is translated into **too late**?
why not use 太迟？ **太迟爱你**.
what is the different between them?

and why does **来不及** mean **too late** in the first place?

- 来=come
- 不=no
- 及=？？

Makes little sense to me.

Comment: If you translate sentence S in language A to B then back to A, you can't expect to get back exactly S. You can of course use 太迟 if you start with English, eg 爱你已太迟

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The break down:

- 「來」(come )
- 「及」implies 「及時」 (in time) here.
- 「得」or 「不」 are the two potential particles that indicate " "able , or "unable"

  *You either **able** or **unable to** come in time.  That's why they are called potential particles.

In summary:

「來」 (come) 「不」(unable to) 「及」 (in time )

「來不及」= unable to come in time = too late

「來不及愛你」= unable to come to love you in time = too late to love you.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to distinguish the two of the phrase:

You use either **来不及做某事** or **做某事太迟了** when you wanna say **too late to do something**
If you want to use 太迟， put the object ahead of 太迟. 太迟爱你 is not even correct in grammar.